# I keep getting an error when i try to use UPDATE to update my database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add 1 to the score every time someone wins the game but i keep getting this error.
I am not really sure what I did wrong.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID = 61a379cd4798f' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\dicegame\update.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dicegame\update.php(16): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dicegame\index.php(161): Update->scoreUpdate(Object(PDO)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dicegame\update.php on line 16
```

```
<?php 
    
class Update{

    private $score;
    private $id;

    public function scoreUpdate($conn){

        $this->id = $_SESSION['id'];

        $sql = "update user set score = score + 1 ID = $this->id";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

    }
}


?>
```

Comment: `score + 1 ID`...you need either a `WHERE` or a `,` before the `ID`, depending on your intent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should have been:

```
$sql = "update user set score = score + 1 where ID = $this->id";
```

You are also wide open to sql injections.

Comment: What is wide open to SQL injection? The OP's code, or your code... and why?

Comment: Me, i was just updating my question.